# What is the relationship between the view controller on the storyboard and view controller I define through code?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

When I create a view controller in the Interface Builder, I associate it with my code version of the class through selecting the appropriate name from the Identity Inspector.  Is the view controller from IB a subclass of the class I coded?

As far as I can tell the view controller in IB is not an instance because you still have to instantiate it:

```swift
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
 // use vc
}
```

I don't think it's a property of the code version of the view controller, `DetailViewController` in the above example.  It's being instantiated through `storyboard`, which in turn is from `UIStoryBoard`.

Comment: Before seeing Sh_Khan's answer, I had interpreted "view controller I define through code" as the VC you created with `storyboard?.instantiateViewController`, but do you actually mean "a VC you created entirely with code, without the help of a storyboard"?

Comment: yes, that's correct.  "a VC you created entirely with code, without the help of a storyboard"

Comment: Okay, then I have misunderstood. Why do you think there is a relationship? A VC that you create with storyboard and one without are just two separate, independent VCs...

Comment: Basically, I want to know what happens when you link the vc on the storyboard to the coded vc through the Identity Inspector, where you can select the name of a class

Comment: Okay, so my answer wasn't too off the mark... Edited and undeleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the storyboard as a *resource file*. `instantiateViewController` just *reads* that file and creates a certain `UIViewController` subclass, by calling its `init(coder:)` initialiser. After that, it creates all the views found on the storyboard, and adds it into the VC's `view`. How does `instantiateViewController` know which `UIViewController` subclass to create? The subclass's name is actually stored in the storyboard, exactly when you type "`DetailViewController`" in the identity inspector!

The View Controller you see in IB is only as much of an instance as this JSON...

```
{
    "username": "Sweeper",
    "id": 5133585
}
```

is an instance of this struct:

```
struct User {
    let username: String
    let id: Int
}
```

It's not a subclass of `DetailViewController` either. It's just data in a resource file.

Comment: I'm confused. You said `instantiateViewController` creates a subclass of `DetailViewController`, but it's not a subclass? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Kevvv it creates a `UIViewController` subclass, which is your `DetailViewController`. It is not a subclass of `DetailViewController`. I never said that.

Answer (score 1):

A storyboard is a collection of scenes / vcs related to each others by a segue if exists , when you create a vc you have the option to create it completely programmatically in terms of it's layout or create it's layout inside a storyboard and then assign the vc name in identity inspector so that you use it to create instance of that vc with `instantiateViewController`   which is linked to the layout specified in storyboard there is no super-subclass relation. the code in vc acts as the series of the vc's life cycle . think of the sotyboard part as an easy way to add the layout components like label / button with constraints to the vc's view instead of creating them programmatically that is the main difference

Comment: Let's say I'm creating a vc using a storyboard and not programmatically. Is the storyboard that represents a vc named "DetailViewController" in itself NOT a class? How is it possible for it be instantiated then through `storyboard?.instantiateViewController`? I still have a vc named "DetailViewController" in a code form elsewhere, which is the actual class.  Surely the storyboard version of "DetailViewController" can't be the same class as the coded version of "DetailViewController" because that'd be a duplicate. I'm just not sure what the entity of that storyboard is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller in the Interface Builder (IB) is not a subclass of the class you define in your `.swift` file. The storyboard really just helps you visually define the layout and constraints of the subviews that a `UIViewController` controls.

Basically what your code snippet is doing is "find the storyboard object with 'Detail' as its identifier, make sure its companion class is of type `DetailViewController`, and then create an instance of `DetailViewController` with the layout and constraints that are defined in that storyboard object".